# Magento Where is the Index File?

Tags: php, magento

I am looking at someones Magento installation in the admin section. The page called home is actually not the template used for the index. I am wondering where I can easily find out what the default template it is using for the index is?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento is an application. The pages you see don't actually exist. They are assembled from multi-level nested code block templates and CMS subsystem entries stored in the database. Their various attribute fields are filled in from the various tables associated with each particular function (category displays, product listings, views, etc.)

index.php is merely a startup file that executes the application known as Magento.

Depending on how this was set up, you need to go to the dropdown menu CMS and look for a page there that will be loaded as the Home page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am used to this setup with things like PHPBB and Wordpress, I do not know enough about magento yet to understand it. I have gone into the manage pages page from the drop down menu and found a home page and the template file that controls it. But that turns out to actually not be the actual index template. None of the pages seem to be the index

Answer (score 0):

Fiasco is absolutely correct. If you want to see some of how that page is rendered, take a look at the layouts and templates at `%magento%/app/design/adminhtml/default/default`. In the `layout` folder there, take a look especially at `main.xml`, which defines adminhtml layout, and `admin.xml`, which defines the layout for the dashboard. Those files will contain references to the many files in `template` that will echo the actual code for that page.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

The page your store uses as it's homepage is stored in the Magento configuration settings.

If you look inside configuration -> web or configuration -> design you will see there's some setting to allow you to use any of your pages as the default index page.

by default this should be the page with key 'home'